# Error: Exception DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (3)

Tags: php

Quiero sumar dias a mi fecha de manera que el intervalo se genere a traves de la variable, pero me da error, busque documentacion y no encontre algo que me guie

Ejemplo:

```
static public function prueba($startsAt = '2021-05-24', $days = 3)
{
    $fechainicial = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $startsAt);

    //como se haria normalmente
    $adddays = new DateInterval('P1D');
    $fechainicial->add($adddays);

    //como quiero hacerlo
    $adddays = new DateInterval($days);
    $fechainicial->add($adddays);
```

El error que muestra:

> Exception
> DateInterval::__construct(): Unknown or bad format (3)

Comment: Y donde esta el error que te sale?

Comment: ahí lo agregue, perdon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El constructor de [DateInterval](https://www.php.net/manual/es/dateinterval.construct.php/) recibe un string como parámetro. Simplemente arma un string con tu variable $days y pásale eso al constructor:

```
static public function prueba($startsAt = '2021-05-24', $days = 3)  
{
 $fechainicial = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $startsAt);

 $adddays = new DateInterval('P'.$days.'D');
 $fechainicial->add($adddays);    
 ...
}
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias buen hombre